# Error when writing code php

Tags: php, variables

if i write code php same:

```
<?php

$title = strip_tags($_POST['title']);

?>
```

unknown error show!

Notice: Undefined index: title in C:\xampp\htdocs\file.php on line 3

Comment: What is `$_POST['title']` ??

Comment: this input in html page!

Comment: The form has to be submitted first.

Comment: In which path the above code and form located? please give the path

Comment: Select answer from below, which is useful to you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_POST has value, after submitting form, so before that anybody can't use $_POST ..

```
   <?php
         if(isset($_POST['title'])){  
//Here in condition if(array_key_exists ( 'title' , $_POST )) can also be checked... 
//OR if(!empty($_POST)) OR if(!empty($_POST['title'])) can also be put..
            $title = strip_tags($_POST['title']);
         }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If both form and action in the same page, the first load will show error as there is no data posted. So first checj whether a `POST` has been made and then assign. Try this

```
$title = "";
if(isset($_POST['title'])){
    $title = strip_tags($_POST['title']);
}
```